# Let $I = [0 , 1]$; let $Q = I \times I$. Define $f: Q \to \mathbb{R}$ by letting $f(x , y) = 1 /q$ if y is rational and $x = p/q$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Let $I = [0 , 1]$; let $Q = I \times I$. Define $f: Q \to \mathbb{R}$ by letting $f(x , y) = 1 /q$
if y is rational and $X = p/q$, where p and q are positive integers with no
common factor; let $f(x, y) = 0$ otherwise.

[image]

I know that this question is already posted here P and here P, but I still do not understand what the answers say or convince me, I would like a clearer answer and for all the questions.

(a) How do I show that $\int_{Q}f$ exists? I have thought that this function is almost zero except in a set of zero measure but I do not know how to use this. One could show that this function is integrable considering cases on $x$ and $y$ as for example that both are rational or irrational? Could that be reduced to the case where $x$ and $y$ are rational? This function is not very similar to the Thomae function?

(b) I think that $\underline{\int_{y\in I}}f(x,y)=\sup\{L(f(x,y),P_B)\}$, where $L(f(x,y), P_B)=\sum_{R_B}m_{R_B}(f)v(R_B)$ and $R_B$ is a rectangle determined by the partition $P_B$ where $P=(P_A,P_B)$ and $P$ is a partition of $Q$. But we know that $\sum_{R_B}m_{R_B}(f)v(R_B)=0$ because in a very small interval we will always find an irrational and so $f(x,y)=0$, with which $\underline{\int_{y\in I}}f(x,y)=0$. I do not know how to calculate $\overline{\int_{y\in I}}f(x,y)$, could someone help me please? I think that $\overline{\int_{y\in I}}f(x,y)=\inf\{U(f(x,y),P_B)\}$, but in this case I do not know which one is $M_{R_B}(f)$.

(c) Fubini's theorem says that if $\int_{Q}f$ exists then $\int_{Q}f=\int_{x\in A}\underline{\int_{y\in I}}f(x,y)=\int_{x\in A}\overline{\int_{y\in I}}f(x,y)$, with which I have to calculate $\int_{x\in A}\underline{\int_{y\in I}}f(x,y)$ and $\int_{x\in A}\overline{\int_{y\in I}}f(x,y)$ and for this I need $\overline{\int_{y\in I}}f(x,y)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Part (a)**

We can show that, given any $\epsilon >0$, there is a partition $P$ of $Q=[0,1]^2$ such that $U(P,f) - L(P,f) < \epsilon$ and the integral exists by the Riemann criterion.

Let $P = P_A \times P_B$ be any partition and $R = R_A \times R_B$ any subrectangle.  The irrational numbers are dense.  Hence, we can always find an irrational $x \in R_A$ (as well as irrational $y \in R_B$). Consequently, there always exist points $(x,y) \in R$ where $f(x,y) = 0$. Since $0 \leqslant f(x,y) \leqslant 1$ everywhere, we have $\inf_R f(x,y) = 0$ for every $R$, and consequently $L(P,f) = 0$.

Given $\epsilon >0$, choose a positive integer $N > 2/\epsilon$ so that $1/N < \epsilon/2$.

The set  $A_N = \{x \in \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]: x = p/q, (p,q) = 1, q \leqslant N \}$ is finite.  Here we have the rational numbers in $[0,1]$ where in lowest terms the denominator in $x = p/q$ is no bigger than $N$.  Let $m$ be the number of elements of $A_N$.

An upper sum can be split into a sum over subrectangles (1) including and (2) excluding points $(x,y)$ with $x \in A_N$:

$$U(P,f) = \sum_{(1)}M_j \, v(R_j) + \sum_{(1)}M_j \, v(R_j) $$

where $M_j$ is the supremum of $f$ over the subrectangle $R_j$.

For the first sum, there are at most $4m$ subrectangles $R_j$ including points where $f(x,y) = 1/q \geqslant 1/N$.  Choosing partition where the largest subrectangle has content less than $\epsilon/(8m)$,  we have

$$\sum_{(1)} \leqslant 4m \cdot \sup_{Q}f(x,y) \cdot \sup_{R_j \in P}v(R_j) \leqslant 4m \cdot 1 \cdot \frac{\epsilon}{8m} = \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

For the second sum, the subrectangles contain no points with $x \in A_N$. Thus $M_j \leqslant 1/N < \epsilon/2$ and

$$\sum_{(2)} \leqslant \epsilon \sum_{(2)} v(R_j) < \frac{\epsilon}{2}.$$

Therefore, there is a partition $P$ such that $U(P,f) < \epsilon$ and since $L(P,f) = 0$ we have

$$U(P,f) - L(P,f) < \epsilon$$

proving that $f$ is Riemann integrable.

Furthermore, we have shown that $\int_{Q} f = 0$ since $\int_Q f = \underline{\int}_Q f = \sup_P L(P,f) = 0$.

**Part (b)**

If $x$ is irrational, then $f(x,y) = 0$ for a all $y \in I$ and, clearly,

$$\underline{\int}_{y \in I} f(x,y) = \overline{\int}_{y \in I} f(x,y)= 0.$$

On the other hand if $x = p/q$ in lowest terms, then $f(x,y) = 0$ if $y$ is irrational and $f(x,y) = 1/q$ if $y$ is rational. Again by density of the rationals we have for any partition $P_B$

$$L(P_B,f(x,\cdot)) = 0, \,\,\, U(P_B,f(x,\cdot)) = 1/q,$$

and, hence,

$$\underline{\int}_{y \in I} f(x,y) = 0, \,\,\, \overline{\int}_{y \in I} f(x,y) = 1/q.$$

**Part (c)**

You should be able to finish this noting from part (b) that we have the Thomae function for

$$\overline{\int}_{y \in I}f(x,y) =  \begin{cases}1/q, \,\,\, x = p/q \\ 0, \quad \,\, x \text{ irrational} \end{cases}$$

Comment: Why $A_N$ is finite? Why "For the first sum, there are at most $4m$ subrectangles $R_j$ including points where $f(x,y)=1/q⩾1/N$"?

Comment: (1) There are only a finite number of rationals in $I$ with $N$ in the denominator: $1/N,2/N,\ldots,N/N$ and even fewer in $A_N$ when $N$ is even since they are in reduced form.  Note that $A_4 = \{1/4,3/4,4/4\}$.  (2) The factor $4m$ is an overestimate but it works for this purpose. A point in $A_N$ could be shared by at most $4$ rectangles if it is located at a common vertex.  If every point in $A_N$ was in the interior of a rectangle then the bound would be $m$.

Comment: Can you say that what is the $L\left(P_{B}, f(x, \cdot)\right)$ for here, what is this mean? There is a 'dot' in your notation, I couldn't understand.

Comment: That is the lower Darboux sum for the function $y \mapsto f(x,y)$ where $x$ is held fixed for partition $P_B$.

Comment: Thanks for comment

Comment: why is there 4m max? An only puts a restriction on x, not y? So technically y can be divided finer than N

Comment: and then there can be much more than 4m subrectangles including (x,y) with x in An if we divide y very finely

Comment: imho, a point in An does not make any sense and is confusing because here a point is (x,y), so could you explain what you mean by 4m and the sum (1) part?

Comment: @james black: Just use a partition with subrectangles of the form $[x_{j-1},x_j] \times [0,1]$ where $\max (x_j - x_{j-1}) < \epsilon/(8m)$.

Comment: I have a question about part b. For any fixed x, f(x,y) over [0,1]  should be constant, and thus it is integrable over [0,1] . But your answer implies the function is not integrable when x = p/q for some specific positive integers p and q. Could help to explain?

Comment: Also, $A_n$ is finite set, but the set of (x,y) with $x \in A_n$ is not finite because y can be arbitrary rational. So, the proof about the upper bound of the upper sum of subrectangles containing such (x,y) is not correct.

Comment: @Hiep No you are misunderstanding here. $A_n$ requires $y$ to be finite. These are the $y$'s that are bounded. The unbounded ones are taken care of by the second sum since the functional values are bounded above by $1/N$.